# Cannot resolve method

Tags: java, android, java-import

Cuando intento compilar este código me salta los errores "cannot resolve method add(?)", "cannot resolve method get(int)" y "cannot resolve method size()" en Android Studio.

Puede ser que me haya dejado de importar alguna cosa?

Los errores aparecen al final del código en las líneas que corresponden al método getFilteredListOfTweets más concretamente.

Saludos y gracias a todos.

Mi código es este:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android_twitter_show_timelines_demo.R;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Result;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterException;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.Tweet;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.TimelineResult;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.TweetTimelineRecyclerViewAdapter;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.UserTimeline;

public class UserTimelineFragment extends Fragment { 

    ...    //Más código    

    private void setUpSwipeRefreshLayout(View view) {

        swipeRefreshLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.user_swipe_refresh_layout);

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {

                if (adapter == null)
                    return;

                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                adapter.refresh(new Callback<TimelineResult<Tweet>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(Result<TimelineResult<Tweet>> result) {
                        TimelineResult<Tweet> filteredTweets = getFilteredListOfTweets(result.body(),"Cupon");
                        //on success response make refreshing false
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Tweets actualizados.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                        // Toast or some other action
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Error al actualizar los tweets.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    public static TimelineResult<Tweet> getFilteredListOfTweets(TimelineResult<Tweet> timelineResult,String wordToFilter){
        TimelineResult<Tweet> filteredTweets = new TimeLineResult<Tweet>();
        for (int i=0;i<timelineResult.size();i++){
            if (timelineResult.get(i).getText().contains(wordToFilter)){
                filteredTweets.add(timelineResult.get(i));
            }
        }
        return filteredTweets;
    }
}
```

Comment: No sé si es un error de transcripción al copiar/pegar, pero en el método success(), al declarar el TimelineResult<Tweet> tienes una barra invertida justo antes.

Comment: Toda la razón al copiarlo se me ha colado, gracias por avisar @Mimmetico

Comment: ¿`TimelineResult` tiene esos metodos?

Comment: Siguiendo lo que comenta @JDev, quizás debes acceder a la colección de items para añadir u obtener: `filteredTweets.items.add` o `filteredTweets.items.get(i)`